# I want to "show" a message only on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, show

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $("#message").show();
    }); 
});
```

HTML:

```
<div id="message">
    <p> You will be their life line, please take your purchase seriously.</p>
</div>
```

This is the code that I have but I want to either show a message on click or animate it but I don't want it visible until clicked.

Comment: You shouldn't be using jQuery let alone javascript if you don't know how to hide an element, try learning basics before doing stuff like this

Comment: This is a little harsh in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

USe css for that

```
#message
{
   display:none;
  }
```

Or you can use jquery too.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#message").hide();
   $("button").click(function(){
    $("#message").show();
   }); 
 });
```

Comment: Why is this downvoted ? It could be better written but I see no big problem.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you need to set display in css:

```
#message{
  display: none;
}
```

And then call the jquery to show it when the button is clicked:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $("#message").show();
    }); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Using CSS:

```
 <div id="message" style="display:none;">
```

Using JS:

```
$('#message').hide();
```